# Reading a set of values from a text file

Tags: java

```
{  
   "TEST":"189456",
   "TEST1":"X_Y_Z",
   "TEST2":"Y_Z_W",
   "TEST3":"GGG  ",
   "TEST4":"32423423233322"
},
{  
   "TEST":"123456",
   "TEST1":"X_E_Z",
   "TEST2":"T_Z_W",
   "TEST3":"EWE ",
   "TEST4":"324234243234"
}
```

This is a `.txt` file I want to read and print only **189456,123456** from the above file.Can anyone help me in doing this.Please find the code for reference.Please post the easiest code.....

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"Test\"\\s*:\\s*\"(.*)\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        while ( (line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            linecount++;

            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

            // indicate all matches on the line
            while (m.find()) {

                 System.out.println(m.group(1));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Although the extension is ```.txt```, why don't you read it in as json?

Comment: What's wrong about the code you provided?

Comment: May just use `if(line.contains("189456") || line.contains("123456"))`

Comment: It is printing the whole line instead what needed for an output

Comment: @alovaros I guess the requirement is to print whatever goes with "TEST", not especially those two numbers ...

Comment: @Fildor oh sorry :) so I missunderstood the question a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for a Regex solution :

```
(.*)\"TEST":\"(.*?)\"
```

Note the  `?` , it makes your regex to stop at the first match of `"`.

With spaces in between :

```
(.*)\"TEST"\s*:\s*\"(.*?)\"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line.contains("\"TEST:\"")){
        String[] lineValues = line.split(":");
        System.out.println(lineValues[1].replace("\"", "").replace(",",""));        
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With provided input, you should read it as json instead of raw text.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
        List<TestObj> test = new ArrayList<TestObj>();
        test = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\YourFile.txt"), test.getClass());
```

Where TestObj is something like this:

```
class TestObj {
    String test;
    String test1;   // You should use json annotation here because it does not match your json field name.
    ...
    // getter setter methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood the question the right way :D

```
String saveData;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"Test\"\\s*:\\s*\"(.*)\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

while ( (line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    linecount++;

    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

    // indicate all matches on the line
    if(line.contains("189456") || line.contains("123456"))  {
        saveData = line;
    }    
}
```

if the String you get from `readLine()` contains the searched string it will save it in saveData

Comment: That won't even compile.

Comment: for only two records to print this will be fine but for multiple records ...that is more than 2 lines??

Comment: Now it compiles but still lightyears away from requirement.

Comment: @Manu so I'd save the Strings I looking for in an array and let contains check if it can find all these? o:

Answer (score 0):

```
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("D:\\prac\\src\\test.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        if(strLine.contains("\"TEST\":")){
            System.out.println(strLine.split(":")[1].replaceAll("\"","").replace(",",""));
        }
    }

    br.close();
}
```

Output:

```
189456
123456
```